# Unable to copy paste data from workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, cell, paste

I have tried to copy data from "to be copied data" to "test macro" using the below, but did not work. Both the workbooks managed to open but did not copy anything across.

I want to copy these cells:

[image: I want to copy these cells]

and paste them to these cells:

[image: to these cells].

```
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\to be copied datat.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\test macro.xlsm")

y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E5").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B3")

x.Close
```

Comment: use [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) or use your method, but you must use in the same way: `y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E5:F7").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Value`

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I have tried `y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E5:F7").Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Value`  I'm not sure why it is not working:(

Comment: This should work `x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3").Copy y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5")`

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Unfortunately, I have just tried it and that did not work too...

Comment: @5377Jay Was there any error?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak There was no error, the file supposed to be copied flashed for like 1 second and then nothing happens at the destination sheet

Comment: @5377Jay That's very strange because this code is 100% working. Do you have an `Option Explicit` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) enabled?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Ah I have it on. I just went to unchecked via the tools and options "Require variable destination" but it the code still did not work. I have also tried creating a brand new workbook to try but to no avail.

Comment: Test it out with your macro recorder and see what the code looks like

Comment: please use `y.Sheets("sheet1").Range("E5").Resize(3, 2).Value = x.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B3")` Then it should work